# Photoshop vs illustrator for icons

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Can photoshop make good icons or illustrator is better right or is there some good plugins for photoshop templates or icon scripts?

Comment: Please provide a bit more information. Where are you going to use these icons? Will it be a set of many or only one? Do you have a specific style or type in mind?   Icons are used everywhere. There are a lot of different requirements for each case. For example: The icons in an icon-font have very different requirements and are built differently compared to an icon for an app or a desktop icon on your computer. I don't think there is an answer that would apply universally. It depends on where the icon(s) will be used and what the icon will have to show.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on who uses the software. For a person that is better and familiar with say photoshop then photoshop is the better tool, atleast in a short term such as for one project.

As for in the long run it depends on what you exactly intend to do, since your question is really sparse in info on the subject  makes impossible to answer.

As for plugins and scripts, again impossible to say. Honestly it sounds a bit premature to talk about additional tools before you can pinpoint what it is your doing.

Comment: I use most for icons and Ui I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Photoshop is one of applications that based on Pixels, but Illustrator is a vector based design program
in this case, icons need to scale in any sizes and you should make them in vectors so illustrator is better.
for more information check this link:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32597/whats-the-difference-between-pixels-and-vectors/

Comment: I dont think its this simple. It depends on far more things, its not like photoshop can not use vectors.

Comment: That's all about vector and pixel, we need vectors for designing logotypes and icons...
the name of Photoshop explain all of things! **Photo**shop

Comment: Yes but its still not that simple, not all icons need infinite scalability. Then manually placing pixels is better. While illustrator has better tools for vector forming, and i pretty much prefer it its still not that simple division. Its  a sort of lie to children to pretend its that straightofward.